# digital ocean docker selenoid

Tags: docker, digital-ocean, selenoid

I created a docker selenoid on digital oceon, i went to the link hub and create a chrome session but when i try to run my python script, the vnc of the session doesn't work !

```
from selenium import webdriver

capabilities = {
    "browserName": "chrome",
    "version": "81.0",
    "enableVNC": True,
    "enableVideo": True
}

driver = webdriver.Remote(
    command_executor="http://myserverip:4444/wd/hub",
    desired_capabilities=capabilities)

driver.get('www.stackoverflow.com')
print('done')
```

Answer (score 0):

In recent Selenium client versions you could solve this by using Selenium protocol extensions as shown here: https://aerokube.com/selenoid/latest/#_specifying_capabilities_via_protocol_extensions